# How to insert a lengthy statement into a php query?

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to insert a lengthy statement (see below) into a query.

```
$q = 
    'SELECT vh12915_fleet.systemHistory.systName, vh12915_space.stars.x, vh12915_space.stars.y
    FROM vh12915_fleet.systemHistory
    INNER JOIN vh12915_space.stars
    ON vh12915_fleet.systemHistory.systName = vh12915_space.stars.name 
    WHERE vh12915_fleet.systemHistory.fleetName = "Fl"';
```

The statement I provided is error-free, as it has been tested in phpMyadmin and worked.

However, when put into a script it produces an error.

What is the right way to put a lengthy statement into a query?
Why does this exact statement work in phpMyAdmin, and not in the script?

Comment: How are you putting it into php when you get the error? Show the example.

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you asking how to execute SQL queries in PHP?  I imagine any introductory PHP tutorial would cover that.

Comment: I edited the post. I just used the = operator and then put the query. The query itself was not recognized by the script for some reason. I know how to execute queries.

Comment: You have to execute the query from php and then read the result from the resultset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With php script

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

    $q = '
    SELECT vh12915_fleet.systemHistory.systName,
           vh12915_space.stars.x,
           vh12915_space.stars.y

    FROM vh12915_fleet.systemHistory
        INNER JOIN vh12915_space.stars
        ON vh12915_fleet.systemHistory.systName = vh12915_space.stars.name

    WHERE vh12915_fleet.systemHistory.fleetName = "Fl"';

    $result = $mysqli->query($q);
    // use result
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: Thanks! Strange, it looks absolutely the same as mine, but this one does work.

Comment: Maybe you use " ? I use ' . because in your where you use : "Fl" so you have to use '.